# Окно на передний план (WIN 10)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-10, qtcreator

Есть два приложения которые работают параллельно (условно 1 и 2). Приложение 2 написано на С++(Qt). Нормальная работа приложения 2 - окно на весь экран с перекрытием меню "Пуск". Когда приложение 1 дает сигнал, приложение 2 должно вывести свое окно на первый план, при этом, закрыть собой весь экран (т.е. панель пуск не видна). На данный момент используются два метода: `show();` и `activateWindow();`.
Но они только выводят окно в перед, при этом не закрывая панель пуск и видно как ярлык мигает желтым цветом.

Ранее уже были проверены еще некоторые методы и функции:

1. `AllowSetForegroundWindow(true);` - нет эффекта.
2. `HWND hand = FindWindowA("LVDChild", "name"); if(hand) SetForegroundWindow(hand);` - помогает с выводом приложения 1, но с приложением 2 такой же эффект как и от `activateWindow();`.
3. `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);` - работает через раз, точнее 1 раз срабатывает и больше не получается.
4. `SetWindowPos ( hwndYourWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE );` ... `SetWindowPos ( hwndYourWindow, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE );` - нет эффекта.

Интересен тот факт, что такое поведение наблюдается только на Windows 10. Ранее приложения стояли на Windows 7 86/64 и Windows 8 86/64 и таких проблем вообще не было.

У кого какие идеи?:)

Comment: raise() - не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, забыл написать.

Comment: А со всем выше написанным showFullscreen не помогает? Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint - по идеи должно делать ваше окно поверх панели задач

Comment: Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint - всего, кроме панели задач, почему-то :(

Comment: В моём случае если использовать showFullscreen то виджет закрывает панель задач под Windows 10

Comment: @Madisson SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE

Answer (score 1):

Функция AllowSetForegroundWindow на самом деле работает, просто передавать ей надо не true, а ID процесса (В данном случае, приложения 2). Кроме того, вызывать ее должно то приложение, которое в данный момент владеет активным окном (т.е. приложение 1). Подробно это все уже обсуждалось [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831776/c-winforms-single-instance-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Answer (score 0):

**работает на Win7:**

```
//Убираем рамки

LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE);

lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_SIZEBOX);

SetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);

//Двигаем окно

SetWindowPos(window, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 1920, 500, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что на Win7 у меня и без 'SetWindowPos' работает, а в десятке нет.