# c#. Winforms. Single-Instance и активация окна при повторном запуске

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Разрабоатываю WinForms  приложение как Single-Instance. При первом вызове запускается как бы «Ядро» приложения, которое затем создает и отображает определенное окно. При последующем запуске приложение проверяет, запущено ли уже приложение и в положительном случае посылает сообщение ядру, передает ему опредленные данные и закрывается. Ядро получает сообщение с параметром, обрабатывает его пределенным образом и создает новую форму и ее оторбражает.
Реализаций подобного есть несколько. Я ипользовал мютексы для проверки существования запущенного приложения и данные передаю при помощи именованных pipes (также пробовал с Remoting). Но есть одна проблема, которая доставляет большое неудобство, а именно, вторая инстанция приложения не получает фокус ввода. Чего я уже только не пробовал, приложение при актвации лишь мигает в таскбаре, а фокус ввода находится там, откуда оно было вызвано.

Я уже и с виндовc API игрался, никак не выходит. Например вызов SetForegroundWindow(HandleRef hWnd) возвращает False. И ничего нельзя сделать.

Как можно решить задачу?

---

Добавление:

Если кто-то захочет помочь, как базис можно использовать например вот эту статью и код. Хотя я использую несколько другой подход, в этом приложении тоже проявляется описанная мною проблема:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/maxim/2010/02/13/single-instance-application-manager/

Просто запускайте приложение из файлового проводника при помощи "Enter", и увидете что фокус ввода при повторном запуске остается в проводнике. Экспериментировать, как я понимаю, нужно здесь:

```
private static void SingleInstanceCallback(object sender, InstanceCallbackEventArgs args)
{
    if (args == null || _mainFrm == null) return;
    Action<bool> d = (bool x) =>
    {
        _mainFrm.ApendArgs(args.CommandLineArgs);
        _mainFrm.Activate(x);
    };
    _mainFrm.Invoke(d, true);
}
```

Comment: Что значит не получает фокус? У вас успешно передаются данные с pipes? Тогда вы должны в коде программы, где у вас эти данные обрабатываются, вызвать самостоятельно фокус на новое окно.

Comment: Form.Focus() пробовал. Не работает.

Comment: Если кто-то захочет помочь, как базис можно использовать например вот эту статью и код. Хотя я использую несколько другой подход, в этом приложении тоже проявляется описанная мною проблема:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/maxim/2010/02/13/single-instance-application-manager/

Comment: Form.Activate() пробовали? Так же можно поиграться с Form.TopMost включая и сразу выключая. Я сам не работал с WinForms, но в WPF Activate() отрабатывал.

Comment: Form.Activate() пробовал, не помогает. Метод Activate() является оберткой для WinApi метода SetForegroundWindow(). Если вызвать в превый раз то этот метод возращает True, последующие разы всегда False

Comment: TopMost вообще опасная штука. Сперва устанавливал на Тrue, и тут жу False. Окно подывается и отображается наверху, но фокус ввода находится под окном! Там, где его вызывали! При начале ввода можно случайно повредить данные.

Comment: В указанном выше проекте есть пример с WPF. Тоже не работает

Comment: В Windows не любой процесс может вызывать SetForegroundWindow, а только тот, который уже "foreground". Так задумано. Переделайте свою систему так, чтобы не упираться в это ограничение.

Comment: Делал так тоже, следил, чтобы окно открывалось из потока, который foreground. Не помогает. Тот же пример в первом ответе не отрабатывает как мне надо.

Comment: Не поток, а процесс. Если процесс не владеет окном переднего плана, он не может вызывать SetForegroundWindow. В ответе, насколько я вижу, та же проблема: если NamedPipeManager_ReceiveString выполняется в свернутом "приложении-ядре", эта схема не рабочая.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight NamedPipeManager_ReceiveString выполняется в первом экземпляре приложения. Последующие попытки запустить экземпляр того же приложения лишь отправит первому сообщение по Pipe, а после закроется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Натолкнулся на одно решение и оно у меня на Windows 10 с небольшими изменениями работает:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319568/how-to-bring-a-form-already-shown-up-to-the-very-foreground-and-focus-it/22737820#22737820

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

    public static void xActivateAndBringToFront(this Form form) {

        // activate window
        var currentForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
        var thisWindowThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(form.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
        var currentForegroundWindowThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(currentForegroundWindow, IntPtr.Zero);
        AttachThreadInput(currentForegroundWindowThreadId, thisWindowThreadId, true);
        form.Activate(); // or: SetForegroundWindow(form.Handle); 
        AttachThreadInput(currentForegroundWindowThreadId, thisWindowThreadId, false);

        // set window to front
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.TopMost = false;
    }
```

---

Дополнение после подсказок от MSDN.WhiteKnight.

MSDN.WhiteKnight указал на то, что применение метода AttachThreadInput может вызывать в некоторых случаях проблемы. Краткий поиск в интернете подтверждает это.

Поэтому, с его же подсказки, я попробовал применить метод AllowSetForegroundWindow. С успехом! А именно, приложение при первом запуске сохраняет ID своего процесса в реестре:

```
Application.UserAppDataRegistry.SetValue(CORE_PROCESS_ID, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
```

Затем, при повторном запуске приложение перед посылкой сообщения ядру вызывает метод AllowSetForegroundWindow:

```
int processID = (int)Application.UserAppDataRegistry.GetValue(CORE_PROCESS_ID);
bool b =  AllowSetForegroundWindow(processID);
// .. сообщение ядру ..
// .. выход ..
```

Ядро создает и отображает окно, окно получает фокус ввода как положено. Не нужно даже как-то принудительно подымать окно. По сути form.Activate() достаточно, но даже этот вызов не нужен, если окно создается и отображается в регламентированном порядке через Show(), ShowDialog() или Application.Run(form).

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что у функции [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) в Windows есть некоторые ограничения. Изменить активное окно может только процесс, который уже владеет активным окном, у которого недавно было свернуто активное окно, в который недавно осуществлялся ввод с помощью клавиатуры или мыши, либо которому явно выдано разрешение на изменение активного окна с помощью *AllowSetForegroundWindow* (есть и другие случаи, см. документацию). Поэтому данная схема работает не всегда. Обходится это довольно просто (на Win7, по крайней мере), перед активацией окна сначала его свернуть и восстановить:

```
private void NamedPipeManager_ReceiveString(string obj)
{
    main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;            
    main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    main.Activate();
}
```

Но в целом, вся схема с мьютексами и каналами для проверки единственности окна программы кажется слишком сложной и ненужной. То же самое можно реализовать гораздо проще, не упираясь в эти ограничения. Существующее окно программы можно найти через *Process.MainWindowHandle*, а для передачи командной строки использовать *WM_COPYDATA*:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int ShowWindow_Restore = 9;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;
            public int cbData;                        
            public IntPtr lpData;
        }

        const uint WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            

            Process this_process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();            

            //найти все процессы с таким же именем
            Process[] other_processes =
                Process.GetProcessesByName(this_process.ProcessName).Where(pr => pr.Id != this_process.Id).ToArray();

            foreach (var pr in other_processes)
            {
                pr.WaitForInputIdle(1000); //на случай, если процесс еще не загрузился

                //берем первый процесс с окном
                IntPtr hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;
                if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) continue;

                //отправляем командную строку
                string command_line = "/activate";
                var cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                cds.dwData = (IntPtr)1;
                cds.cbData = (command_line.Length + 1) * 2;
                cds.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(command_line);
                SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(cds.lpData);

                //активируем окно и выходим
                ShowWindow(hWnd, ShowWindow_Restore);
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            //если ничего не найдено, продолжаем работу
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_COPYDATA)
            {
                COPYDATASTRUCT data = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                data = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, data.GetType());                
                textBox1.Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.lpData);                 
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }    

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
            textBox1.Select();
        }

    }           

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, я отметил ответ как полезный. Но здесь нет возможности передачи аргументов приложения. И вообще мое приложение имеет еще одну особенность, а имено, в нем не нужно активировать главное окно приложения, а нужно создать и показать новое окно (с фокусом ввода). И вообще, в моем оригинальном приложении, у меня запускаются несколько основных циклов  приложения (Application.Run(context) про инстанцию приложения). Я не стал об этом сразу писать, т.к. проблема проявляется и в более упрощенном виде.

Comment: @SergejLoos Для создания новых окон правила те же, что и для активации. Если процесс не подпадает под условия, окно будет создано на заднем плане. И точно так же трюк со сворачиванием/разворачиванием окна позволяет это обойти.

Comment: В моем случае этот трюк c Minimized-Normal не срабатывает :(

Comment: Но я натолкнулся на следующее решение и оно на первый взгляд работает: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319568/how-to-bring-a-form-already-shown-up-to-the-very-foreground-and-focus-it/22737820#22737820

Comment: @SergejLoos Лучше все же смотреть в сторону "легального" способа - AllowSetForegroundWindow. Неизвестно, к чему может привести вызов AttachThreadInput для потоков из разных процессов.

Comment: У меня метод AllowSetForegroundWindow возвращает False, как и последующий после него вызов SetForegroundWindow. К сожалению не работает

Comment: @SergejLoos Если вызывать из того же процесса, конечно не работает. AllowSetForegroundWindow нужно вызывать из процесса, уже имеющего право вызова SetForegroundWindow (процесс-отправитель будет его иметь, если в нем создать хотя бы одно окно).

Comment: Не пойму, что имеется ввиду. Ведь окна создаются в одном процессе. Создает их основной процесс, ядро, которое получает для этого уведомление через pipes. Ядро "сидит" в системном трее (справи внизу значек), но не имеет никаких визуальных форм (может быть в этом проблема?).

Comment: @SergejLoos Я имею в виду процесс, который отправляет сообщение ядру через Pipe. Он должен перед этим вызвать AllowSetForegroundWindow на ядро, чтобы ваша схема заработала.

Comment: Действительно. Переписал код так, что ядро сохраняет ID своего процесса в registry. Затем при повторном запуске приложения, перед отравкой сообщения ядру, вычитывается ID и вызывается AllowSetForegroundWindow. Теперь для поднятия окна достаточно вызова form.Activate(); Не нужно никакого TopMost. Я очень благодарен тебе, WhiteKnight!

Answer (score 1):

Странно. Activate() у меня отрабатывает. Сейчас приведу свой пример программы.

Вот PipeManager, который я использовал. Писал не я, сам нашёл где-то (уже не помню где).

```js
    public class NamedPipeManager
    {
        public static string NamedPipeName { get; } = "MyApplicationName";
        public event Action<string> ReceiveString;

        private const string EXIT_STRING = "__EXIT__";
        private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

        public void Start()
        {
            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
            backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            Write(EXIT_STRING);
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker.Dispose();
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReceiveString?.Invoke(e.UserState as string);
        }

        private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string result;
                using (var server = new NamedPipeServerStream(NamedPipeName))
                {
                    server.WaitForConnection();

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server))
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                if (result == EXIT_STRING)
                    break;

                backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, result);
            }
        }

        public static bool Write(string[] text, int connectTimeout = 300)
        {
            using (var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(NamedPipeName))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(connectTimeout);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (!client.IsConnected)
                    return false;

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client))
                {
                    foreach (var a in text)
                        writer.Write(a + '\n');
                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static bool Write(string text, int connectTimeout = 300)
        {
            using (var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(NamedPipeName))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(connectTimeout);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (!client.IsConnected)
                    return false;

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client))
                {
                    writer.Write(text);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

В Program.cs я добавляю 3 статичных поля:

```
 static Mutex Mutex;
 static NamedPipeManager NamedPipeManager;
 static Form1 main;
```

В Main() я в начало добавляю это:

```
 Mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyApplicationName", out bool Is);
 if (!Is)
 {
     NamedPipeManager.Write("1");
     Application.Exit();
     return;
 }
 NamedPipeManager = new NamedPipeManager();
 NamedPipeManager.ReceiveString += NamedPipeManager_ReceiveString;
 NamedPipeManager.Start();
```

Естественно в поле main я храню свою основную форму. А событием ReceiveString вызываю этот метод:

```
 private static void NamedPipeManager_ReceiveString(string obj)
 {
     if (main.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
         main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
     main.Activate();
 }
```

Специально сейчас попробовал по быстрому написать этот пример. Запускаю один раз приложение - появляется окно. Потом фокусируюсь обратно на проводник, запускаю - опять открывается первое окно. Если сверну и запускаю с проводника, то опять же первоначальное окно запускается.

[image: Как работет]

Comment: Кстати огромное спасибо за подробный ответ и возьню со мной. После запуска из проводника во второй раз, где находися фокус? Можно проверить, если нажать, например, клавиши вверх или вниз. Если прозойдет выбор следующего файла - проявление моей проблемы

Comment: @SergejLoos Я добавил на форму TextBox, на который при активации окна и кидается фокус.

Comment: Повторил этот пример. Фокус не кидается, а остается в проводнике. Windows 10

Comment: @SergejLoos ну честно говоря даже не знаю в чём у вас конкретно проблема. .NET 4.6.1 стоит в качестве целевой платформы. Других отличий быть не может. А что именно происходит? Вы запустили приложение, после переключились на проводник и запустили ещё раз. У вас окно выходит на передний план и фокус остаётся на проводнике или окно вообще не выходит? Вообще NamedPipeManager_ReceiveString отрабатывается, через деббагер пробовали?

Comment: Если окно было свернуто, или в него недавно что-то вводили, тогда работает. А если из окна просто переключиться на другое, ничего не делая, не работает (Win 7)