# Какой перечень манипуляций нужно произвести чтобы выдвинуть окно на передний план

Tags: c++, winapi

Пробовал советы из темы [Окно на передний план (WIN 10)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625790/%d0%9e%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd-win-10) но не помогло, уже на 3ьем форуме задаю вопрос.

```
 char*put="C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
STARTUPINFOA start_info={sizeof start_info};
PROCESS_INFORMATION proc_info={0};
CreateProcessA(put,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,&start_info,&proc_info);
 Sleep(10000);//для того чтобы приложение загрузилось нормально нужно пока оставить
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc,proc_info.dwProcessId);//окно придётся находить
//SetWindowLongA(g_HWND,); 
LONG lStyle = GetWindowLongA(g_HWND,GWL_STYLE);
lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_SIZEBOX);
SetWindowLong(g_HWND,GWL_STYLE, lStyle);

SetWindowPos(g_HWND,HWND_TOPMOST,400,400,400,400,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);//cout<<<<endl;
DWORD qq_=GetLastError();
char gh;
cin>>gh;cout<<"gh "<<gh<<" код ошибки "<<qq_<<endl;//если убрать эту строку то мы не увидим маленько окно перемещённое на передний план

//т.к. программа отработает очень быстро или таймер нужен
DWORD ExitCode=0;
GetExitCodeProcess(proc_info.hProcess,&ExitCode);
TerminateProcess(proc_info.hProcess,ExitCode);
CloseHandle(proc_info.hProcess);
```

Comment: `AllowSetForegroundWindow(proc_info. айди_процесса ) ` и за тем `SetForegroundWindow` ставили? Версия win какая?

Comment: Виндовс 7. Эту комбинацию тоже пробовал, но попробую ещё раз на всякий случай, но не суть тут речь идёт ещё и о том чтобы менять размер окна а этим занимается SetWindowPos и как ни крути но с ней всё равно придётся разбираться.

Comment: AllowSetForegroundWindow(proc_info. айди_процесса )  и за тем SetForegroundWindow не работает.